# Git pre-commit hook to run `npm test` on CMD (Windows)

Tags: javascript, windows, git, githooks

I've created a `.bat` (`pre-commit-tests.bat`) file with the content:

```
cd ../../BUILD
npm test
```

in the project's `.git\hooks` directory.

when I do commit, it seems to show the CMD window for a brief second and close it, I don't know why my tests are not running or how to keep the CMD window open even after it finishes, so at least maybe read any output (if there's a problem).

If I manually run `npm test` (which is a task configured in my `package.json` file, then it does work and the tests are running (takes about 4 seconds to run). 
*(complex mocha tests running on slimerjs)*.

#### I'm using TortoiseGit to configure Git hooks like so:

[image]

Why doesn't it run the command using the hook correctly?
Did I write the hook file wrong?

Comment: Add `pause` at the end of the `.bat` to keep it open

Comment: it seems like path issue, not sure. also adding `pause` to the `bat` file won't pause it in the end and it will get closed

Comment: Seeing [javascript], you may be interested in [`git-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-hooks) or [`pre-commit`](https://github.com/observing/pre-commit)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus - Thanks but even though I think it's a total overkill to install an NPM script for something so simple, I have tried, and it does not work since my `.git` folder is in a parent directory, which is not supported by the script. anyway, I want this to work as it should.